# Share and accessing radio button text value between two kotlin files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I have an application that starts with 2 radio buttons.

When l click in one of them I can recuperate its text value in the current file. But when i try to access this value in another file it does not change even If i click in the other button !!

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
public var rbt= "French"
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_main)

    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

    val assistantFragment = AimyboxAssistantFragment()

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {

        replace(R.id.assistant_container, assistantFragment)
        commit()
    }

}
// Get the selected radio button text using radio button on click listener
fun radio_button_click(view: View){
    // Get the clicked radio button instance
    val radio: RadioButton = findViewById(radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId)
    rbt=radio.text.toString()
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"On click : ${rbt}",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val assistantFragment = (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.assistant_container)
            as? AimyboxAssistantFragment)
    if (assistantFragment?.onBackPressed() != true) super.onBackPressed()
}
```

}

The other file (AimyboxApplication.kt) where i want to access the radio button text value :

```
class AimyboxApplication : Application(), AimyboxProvider {

companion object {
    private const val AIMYBOX_API_KEY = ""
}

override val aimybox by lazy { createAimybox(this) }

private fun createAimybox(context: Context): Aimybox {
    val unitId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    val textToSpeech = GooglePlatformTextToSpeech(context, Locale.getDefault())
    val speechToText = GooglePlatformSpeechToText(context, Locale.getDefault())
    //speechToText.toString()
    var rbt = MainActivity().rbt

    if (rbt=="English"){
        println("English")
    }
    if (rbt=="French"){
        println("French")
    }
    // Do something
}
```

}

layout_activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/logo"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/fr">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:padding="18dp"
        android:text="@string/prompt"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/en"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="English"
        android:onClick="radio_button_click"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/fr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="French"
        android:onClick="radio_button_click"/>


</RadioGroup>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/assistant_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</FrameLayout>
```

When I start the app, it print me always "French" even if I clicked in English radio button !!

Thanks.

Comment: You left an API key in your pasted code, just in case that's a problem

Answer (score 1):

Consider these things:

1. In `createAimybox` method and this code`MainActivity().rbt`, this code will
   create new instance of `MainActivity`, and in that activity you have
   predefined `public var rbt= "French"`. That's why, it is printing
   `French` value.
2. `AimyboxApplication` class will be called before activity start as it is application, also this class will be called only once. So now even if you change value inside `MainActivity`, application class method will not be triggered automatically(also it is different object MainActivity), you have to put some logic. But it is not recommended to use such logic at Application level as it will be changing.

**EDIT:**

Let me give you simple solution for this:

First add this `LanguagePref` class.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
const val LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE = "preferenceData"
const val LANGUAGE_DATA = "languageData"

public enum class LANGUAGE_ENUM(languageCode:String){
     ENGLISH("English"),
     FRENCH("French")
}

public class LanguagePref(val context: Context) {
    private val mPreferences: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        context.getSharedPreferences(
            LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
    }
    private val mEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor by lazy { mPreferences.edit() }

    public fun saveLanguage(
        langauage: String
    ) {
        mEditor
            .putString(LANGUAGE_DATA, langauage)
            .apply()
    }

    public fun getLanaguage(): String {
        return mPreferences.getString(LANGUAGE_DATA, LANGUAGE_ENUM.ENGLISH.name)!!
    }
}
```

Now in your main activity inside button click event you can save language like this:

```
val languagePref =LanguagePref(this)
languagePref.saveLanguage(LANGUAGE_ENUM.ENGLISH.name)
//languagePref.saveLanguage(LANGUAGE_ENUM.FRENCH.name)//For FRENCH language
```

Also you should use `aimybox` and `createAimybox` inside `MainActivity`, not at application level:

```
 override val aimybox by lazy { createAimybox(this) }

    private fun createAimybox(context: Context): Aimybox {
        val unitId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

        val textToSpeech = GooglePlatformTextToSpeech(context, Locale.ENGLISH)
        val speechToText = GooglePlatformSpeechToText(context, Locale.ENGLISH)

        val dialogApi = AimyboxDialogApi(AIMYBOX_API_KEY, unitId)
        var rbt = LanguagePref(this).getLanaguage()

        if (rbt==LANGUAGE_ENUM.ENGLISH.name){
            println("English")
        }
        if (rbt==LANGUAGE_ENUM.FRENCH.name){
            println("French")
        }
        return Aimybox(Config.create(speechToText, textToSpeech, dialogApi))
    }
```

Because application level code will not be called again. Also it is mentioned in `Aimybox` document. You can check it by, `(CTRL+ Right click)` on `aimybox` inside `AimyboxApplication` class, and it will open  this interface:

```
/**
 * Implement the interface in your Activity or Application to start using Aimybox components
 * */
interface AimyboxProvider {
    /**
     * Main class of the Aimybox library. You should have only one instance of the class for correct behavior.
     * */
    val aimybox: Aimybox
    /**
     *
     * */
    fun getViewModelFactory() = AimyboxAssistantViewModel.Factory.getInstance(aimybox)
}
```

If you look at the comment it is stating `Activity or Application` :

```
/**
 * Implement the interface in your Activity or Application to start using Aimybox components
 * */
```

Comment: Thanks @keyur for your reply.
So what do you suggest ?

Comment: It is depend on your requirements what you want to do. Please explain what exactly you want to do.

Comment: what i want to do is simple. 
When starting the application, I choose the language by taping in one radio button and then I want get the text value of the radio button clicked in the file AimyboxApplication.kt precisely in the method createAimybox()

Answer (score 0):

Keyur's right about the value, you're not accessing the one you stored, you're creating a whole new activity with the default value (`"French"`) so that's what you read in.

You have a few options, depending on how your app is set up. Easiest is to just call `createAimybox()` directly when the language is set, and pass the language as a parameter. If you're doing it between activities (instead of holding it in the Application), you should pass data as extras in an `Intent` bundle.

It might be a better choice to store it in `SharedPreferences` and tell the target to grab the current value - that way the `createAimybox` function can just look up what the current setting is, and it will persist between app sessions too, if that's important.

I'm guessing because `aimybox` is a `lazy` property it gets initialised after the user sets their language, but then it's permanently fixed until the app is closed and restarted. So if you want the user to be able to change the language without restarting the app, you'll need to do things in a different way.

Comment: yes @cactustictacs. 
i am new to android. can you tell me where and how can I call createAimybox() directly when the language is set?